# Gnuplot with epslatex: How to nagate error while generating output

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have the following script which generates a single .eps file as the final output

```
set terminal epslatex color size 4.5in,4.5in standalone
set output 'profile.tex'
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "$d_g$"
set xrange [:500000]
set yrange [:40]
set size ratio 1.05
set key right bottom
pl 'file.txt' u 2:(17.75-$4) w l
unset out
set out
system('latex profile.tex && dvips profile.dvi && ps2pdf profile.ps')
system('mv profile.ps CON_GBD.eps')
unset terminal
set out
```

While using the above script I get the following error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.175     \gplfronttext

?
```

Can anyone point out as to why this error comes up?

Comment: I think, it's the automatic key entry which make problems, because it contains a `$`. Earlier versions of gnuplot didn't escape such characters correctly. Don't remember when it was fixed. Either upgrade, or set a custom key entry with `plot... title 'my title' `

Comment: @Christoph you are probably right, as after a custom key entry even with ' $title$ ' it had no issues.